Routes in Quart not working when registered in a separate function
I'm developing a Quart application and have noticed that when I define routes directly in app.py, they work as expected. However, when I try to register these routes using a separate function (e.g., register_routes(app)), the routes are not detected.
This is not working:
app.py:
from quart import Quart
from routes import register_routes

app = Quart(__name__)
register_routes(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

routes.py:
def register_routes(app):
    @app.get('/hello')
    async def hello():
        return {'message': 'Hello, World!'}

But this is working:
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)
@app.get('/hello')
async def hello():
    return {'message': 'Hello, World!'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


I can't reproduce this behavior. Your first example -- which registers routes in the register_routes function -- works just fine for me; requesting http://localhost:5000/hello returns the expected JSON response.
